# NSString format issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsstring

I have NSString like `"Circular Quay W, The Rocks NSW, Australia"` and I want to display in following string format:

```
Circular Quay W,
The Rocks NSW,
Australia
```

so please help me to develop this functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format the question correctly so that we can understand the input and output more clearly.

Comment: Where do you want to display it? What have you tried?

Comment: It looks like you're displaying an address. If you have more in that program, try creating an Address structure and writing a description function that automatically formats it. This is an ADT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you are displaying the string in a `UILabel`.

```
NSString *str = @"Circular Quay W, The Rocks NSW, Australia";
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@", " withString:@",\n"];
```

Don't forget to set *numberOfLines* of the label to *0*. This lets the label to show multiline text.

```
label.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

replace each comma with (comma and new line ",\n"), if you're showing it in a `UILabel` make sure to set the height and the number of lines first to **0** using property `numberOfLines`.

```
 NSString *stringFoo = @"Circular Quay W, The Rocks NSW, Australia";
 stringFoo = [stringFoo stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"," withString:@",\n"];
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do the job:

`[NSString stringWithString:@"Circular Quay W,\n The Rocks NSW,\n Australia"];`

Cheers